# Reindexing data frame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a data set for training and testing using Pandas.

```
data = pd.read_csv("housingdata.csv", header=None)
train = testing.sample(frac=0.6)
train.reindex()
test  = testing.loc[~testing.index.isin(train.index)]
print train
print test
```

when I print the data, I get

```
         0     1     2  3      4
9  0.17004  12.5  7.87  0  0.524
1  0.02731   0.0  7.07  0  0.469
5  0.02985   0.0  2.18  0  0.458
3  0.03237   0.0  2.18  0  0.458
7  0.14455  12.5  7.87  0  0.524
6  0.08829  12.5  7.87  0  0.524

         0     1     2  3      4
0  0.00632  18.0  2.31  0  0.538
2  0.02729   0.0  7.07  0  0.469
4  0.06905   0.0  2.18  0  0.458
8  0.21124  12.5  7.87  0  0.524
```

As noticed, the row indices are re-shuffled. How to re-index the rows in both the data sets?

This however does not change global settings. Eg.,

```
train.iloc[0,4]
```

gives 0.524

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to reset the index after sampling? e.g. restart both slices from `0`? you can call `reset_index(drop=True)` to do this, `reindex` is literally to select rows from your df using the passed in indices, or you want to sort the index?

Comment: That is exactly what I want. The first column should look like, 0,1,2,...
reset_index(drop=True) did not work

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your desired output as it's not clear what you're after

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @EdChum's comments point out, it's not exactly clear what behavior you're looking for.  But if all you want to do is to give both new dataframes indices going from `0, 1, 2 ... n` then you can use [`reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
train.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
test.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out. Thanks a lot. :)